# Solution of the ODE $x'=t+x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

How can i find the general solution of

$$x'=t+x$$

I tried a few things, but I couldn't get to the solution, I don't think I'm remembering the right method to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you learned the method of integrating factor?

Comment: Move the x to the other side, solve for t=0 for a general solution the use that to get the particular solution for t as a variable

Comment: try a particular solution of the form $x=at+b$

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/linear.aspx#:~:text=The%20solution%20process%20for%20a,)%20%2C%20using%20(10)%20.&text=Integrate%20both%20sides%2C%20make%20sure,with%20the%20constant%20of%20integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use "variation of constants technique". You start by solving the homogeneous equation $x'-x = 0$, which yields the general solution $x(t)=c e^t$. Then you assume that the solution of your equation is of the form $x(t)=c(t) e^t$ and determine $c(t)$:

$$
(c(t) e^t)' = c(t) e^t + t\Leftrightarrow c'(t) e^t+c(t) e^t = c(t) e^t+t\Leftrightarrow c'(t)=t e^{-t}\Rightarrow c(t)=-(t+1)e^{-t} + k
$$

Finally, you get $x(t)=-(t+1) + ke^t$.

Comment: In this case, is $k$ determined by the initial condition? Right?

Comment: @Mrcrg correct, the initial condition will set $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x'=t+x$$
$$x'-x=t$$
With integrating factor method. Multiply both sides by $\mu (t)$:
$$\mu (t)=e^{-t}$$
The Differential equation becomes:
$$x'e^{-t}-xe^{-t}=te^{-t}$$
$$(xe^{-t})'=te^{-t}$$
Integrate.